# Javascript wait for condition to be true using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, electron, settimeout

I am struggling to make a simple waiting function in my program. I want to use promises and async await if possible. What I have so far:

```
 function waitForCondition(conditionObj) {
   var start_time = new Date().getTime()

   function checkFlag() {
     if (conditionObj.arg == conditionObj.test) {
       console.log('met');
       return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
     } else if (new Date() > start_time + 3000) {
       console.log('not met, time out');
       return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
     } else {
       window.setTimeout(checkFlag, 1000); 
     }
   }
   checkFlag();
 }

  async function run() {
    console.log('before');
    await waitForCondition({arg: '1', test: '1'})
    console.log('after');
  }
  run();
```

It should check every 1 second for a maximum time of 3 seconds. The console should look like this:

```
'before'
'met'
'after'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to `return` a promise:

```js
function waitForCondition(conditionObj) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var start_time = Date.now();
    function checkFlag() {
      if (conditionObj.arg == conditionObj.test) {
        console.log('met');
        resolve();
      } else if (Date.now() > start_time + 3000) {
        console.log('not met, time out');
        resolve();
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(checkFlag, 1000); 
      }
    }
    checkFlag();
  });
}

async function run() {
  console.log('before');
  await waitForCondition({arg: '1', test: '1'})
  console.log('after');
}
run();
```

I refactored your code a bit. To get the current time, use `Date.now()`. And you should be OK with calling `resolve` without a timeout of 1 millisecond.

Comment: Yes, but please don't write the promise logic like that. You should promisify `setTimeout` and nothing else.

Comment: @petermader thank you for the amazing answer this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm new to this. It would be helpful if you could explain why?

Comment: @HansBouwmeester Basically because you are loosing all the benefits of promises  with that, like chainability and implicit error handling. Apart from not catching exceptions, the non-promise code becomes harder to modify when you want to add another asynchronous (promise) call, you are more likely to fall for the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are really looking for is

```
function waitForCondition(conditionObj) {
  var start_time = new Date().getTime()

  async function checkFlag() {
    if (conditionObj.arg == conditionObj.test) {
      console.log('met');
       // return something?
    } else if (new Date() > start_time + 3000) {
      console.log('not met, time out');
      // throw some error?
    } else {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      return checkFlag();
    }
  }
  return checkFlag();
}
```

or with a loop instead of the recursion

```
async function waitForCondition(conditionObj) {
  var start_time = new Date().getTime()

  while (true) {
    if (conditionObj.arg == conditionObj.test) {
      console.log('met');
      break; // or return
    }
    if (new Date() > start_time + 3000) {
      console.log('not met, time out');
      break; // or throw
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, though in my opinion it's not a good idea to use recursion here (as there's no need to place anything on the stack). I think the 2nd example is the way to go.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester I posted the recursive implementation mostly because the OP had started with a recursive idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `waitForCondition` implicitely returns `undefined`. try to add a return statment at the end of it:

```
return checkFlag();
```

And as mentionned in comment, there one condition where `checkFlag()` returns `undefined` that you might want to handle by returning a `Promise`.

Comment: But just adding  a `return` isn't enough. `checkFlag()` will return undefined if the condition isn't met yet.